# Hacer una app android se inicie al iniciar android

Tags: android, android-studio

Hola que tal? Estoy trabajando en una app bajo android-studio. Quiero hacer una opción en mi aplicación que diga "iniciar cuando del dispositivo se encienda", que la aplicación misma verifique si esta inicia cuando enciende el equipo y auto-tilde la opción, de lo contrario no, que cuando funcione, como se pueden dar cuenta, se inicie la aplicación cuando android inicie. Cono es posible esto? Estoy buscando y no se como hacerlo gracias

Comment: espero mi respuesta te ayude :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Lo que necesitas es usar un Broadcast Receiver que escuche esta acción
>   `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED`, con eso se puede detectar cuando el equipo
>   terminó el reinicio.

Te pongo este código de ejemplo

Declaras lo siguiente en tu AndroidManifest:

**Permiso**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

**Broadcast Receiver**

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

**Luego creas tu BroadCast Receiver**

```
package tu.paquete;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class TuBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //cuando detecta la acción del reinicio completado, inicias tu activity
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, TuActividad.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    }

}
```

Te dejo un link de ejemplo por si deseas: [Realizar acción después del reinicio](http://www.compiletimerror.com/2014/12/android-autostart-app-after-boot-with.html)

Comment: muchas gracias!

Comment: no hay problema :)

Comment: Hola @diegoveloper he intentado todos los pasos que colocaste al pie de la letra, en android 7 funciona perfecto, pero en android 8, 9 o 10 no funciona. Alguna sugerencia. Gracias

Comment: @Isabel , podrías intentar con esta respuesta, veo que está más actualizada : https://stackoverflow.com/a/63250729/666221 , si te funciona nos avisas para enlazar esta respuesta con la nueva

Comment: Gracias @diegoveloper, voy a probar lo que me sugeriste, luego te cuento como me va, gracias